# Latin characters not working in html5 using UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, html, utf-8

Hey so i'm getting text with latin characters like "ó" from a mysql database. This is the connection along with the query i'm using to get the data, placing it in an array:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $con=new mysqli ("localhost","root","","chroniclemark");

    $sqlget = "SELECT descricao FROM items;";
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,$sqlget) or die ('error getting database');
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $lol5[] = $row['descricao'] ;
     }?>
```

I'm then trying to display the the text outside of the `<?php ?>` statement like so:

```
<p ><?php echo $lol5[0]; ?></p>
```

All of the text is fine except for the "ç", "ó", "ã" and so on.
I also have a meta tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my header but it doen't help.
In the database, the data is set to "utf8mb4_unicode_ci".
What can i do to fix this? Any idea?

Comment: pass utf-8 to the "connection" first. Works 9 times out of 10.

Comment: @Fred -ii Hey how are you doing Fred, what do you mean with pass?

Comment: Great, thanks Mark; hope the same for you. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through there are examples in there and more information to read.

Comment: @Fred -ii- It works now! many thanks

Comment: You're welcome Mark; it was a duplicate though but glad you got your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Fred -ii Thanks for pointing me in the right direction in the comments.
All i had to do was use `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');` before making the query

```
$sqlget = "SELECT descricao FROM items;";
 $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,$sqlget) or die ('error getting database');
```

It's all fine now :)